# Recommended way to interact with MySQL in Play framework (scala)?

Tags: scala, orm, playframework

I'm a newbie, just started using **Play** framework (2.8.x). Is there any recommended way to interact with MySQL in Play framework using **ORM** framework (**slick** or something else ?? after I searched around)? As I usually interact with MySQL in **Flask** using **SQLAlchemy** under Python, I'd wish to do something likewise under scala.

Comment: SQLAlchemy is an ORM framework, so you' likely would want some ORM as well. Slick is one option, but there are also other: this post might give you a good starting point for further research: https://softwaremill.com/comparing-scala-relational-database-access-libraries/ (it's a bit old though).

I'm afraid I'm going to vote to close this question, as there are really no question so far :) Please do the research on what fits your needs better, and come back if you face any problems with whatever lib you pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one recommended way of doing database calls on Scala.

When it comes to Play Framework, then quite often it was used together with Slick because of who developed them. But Slick is Functional-Relational-Mapping, not Object-Relational-Mapping.

If you want to use ORM, you would have to use Hibernate as many people came to conclusion that ORMs do more harm than good in a long run, so nobody develops any ORM solution. (Not intending to argue about it here, just explaining why you won't find native ORM Scala solution that is maintained today).

When it comes to where community leans, you should consider some "safe SQL builder" like Doobie, Quill or jOOQ.

But as I said, nobody will ever tell you that there is some one solution that everybody would pick no matter what.